# Как закрыть клиентское соединение в libevent?

Tags: c++, http, клиент-сервер, libevent

Как закрыть клиентское соединение средствами библиотеки libevent (на с++) после получения ответа от сервера, чтобы файловый дескриптор используемый соединением освободился?

Схема по которой происходит отправка запроса:

```
struct evhttp_connection *conn;
struct evhttp_request *req;

conn = evhttp_connection_new(addr, port);
evhttp_connection_set_timeout(conn, timeout);
evhttp_connection_set_retries(conn, count_of_retry_sending);
evhttp_connection_free_on_completion(conn);
evhttp_connection_set_closecb(conn, callback_close_connection, nullptr);

// привязка обработчика ответа к соединению
req = evhttp_request_new(response_handler, static_cast<void*>(context));

// заполнение выходного буфера данными
// ......

// отправка запроса
evhttp_make_request(conn, req, EVHTTP_REQ_POST, resource);
```

При просмотре под отладчиком захода в callback_close_connection обнаружил, что  закрытие соединения происходит минут через 5 после ответа от сервера. Непонятно почему соединение не закрывается сразу после получения ответа.

Comment: Потому что вы можете использовать его повторно для ускорения.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение. Убрал строчки:

```
evhttp_connection_free_on_completion(conn);
evhttp_connection_set_retries(conn, count_of_retry_sending);
```

Указатель на соединение передал в функцию обработчик ответа от сервера, где вызывал по окончании обработки `evhttp_connection_free(conn);`